# Regex pattern to grab a changing part of a section

Tags: java, regex

How would I grab the substring between the 'nick=' and the ',' in the statement: 'nick=StringIWantIsHere,'?

I have been trying to figure it out and I am only able to grab the nick= but I cant seem to grab only the string after that. (The string I want changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
"nick=(.*?),"
```

**Demo:**

```
String mydata = "nick=StringIWantIsHere,";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("nick=(.*?),");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: When I use this it print the nick=String, How would I get the String part only?

Comment: This works as expected for me. Are you sure it's the same code?

Answer (score 0):

> How would I grab the substring between the 'nick=' and the ',' in the statement: 'nick=StringIWantIsHere,

You can use this lookbehind regex:

```
(?<=nick=)[^,]+
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eB8oS9)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
s = s.replaceAll(".*=(.*?),.*", "$1");
```